# fancybox.close() and open another fancybox

Tags: fancybox

Is the first time that I'am using this forum.

My problem is that I want to close a fancybox to open another fancybox. And for that I am using in my code the `parent.$.fancybox.close()` to close the Fancybox Iframe Window. When the user click in the Add to cart button. The fancybox close and my program in js STOP running. Example:

```
$(x).click(function(){
    parent.$.fancybox.close();  

    idCombination = $('#idCombination').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
        data: 'controller=cart&add=1&ajax=true&qty=' + $('#quantity_wanted').val() + '&id_product=' + id_product + '&token=' + static_token + ( (parseInt(idCombination) && idCombination != null) ? '&ipa=' + parseInt(idCombination): ''),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loading_img').show();
        },
        success: function(q) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: path + "ajaxcart/pop_up.php",data:'referer='+document.referrer,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $(".shop").show();
                    $('#loading_img').show();
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    $(".shop").show();
                    $("#shopping").show();
                    $('#loading_img').hide();
                    $('#shopping').html(res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 300}, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: try placing `parent.$.fancybox.close()` in the last `success` callback

Comment: Hi JFK.! Thank you very much for your help. I have done your suggestion. I have placed parent.$.fancybox.close() in last success callback. But with no success. The fancybox close and the other fancybox not open. When i use parent.$.fancybox.close() the js program end and exit. Thank you.